# Confusing definition of thermodynamic pressure when calculating the electron degeneracy pressure

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, fermions, fermi-energy

When dealing with statistical mechanics, one usually defines pressure as
$$p(N,T,V,X):=-\frac{\partial F(N,T,V,X)}{\partial V}.$$
In engineering thermodynamics, I've often seen this definition reformulated in terms of the Legendre transform $U=F\{S\leftrightarrow T\}$:
$$
p(N,T,V,X):=-\frac{\partial }{\partial V}\left(U(N,S(N,T,V,X),V,X)-TS(N,T,V,X))\right)\\=-\frac{\partial U(N,S,V,X) }{\partial S}|_{S=S(N,T,V,X)}\frac{\partial S(N,T,V,X)}{\partial V}-\frac{\partial U(N,S,V,X) }{\partial V}|_{S=S(N,T,V,X)}+T\frac{\partial S(N,T,V,X)}{\partial V}\\=-\frac{\partial U(N,S,V,X) }{\partial V}|_{S=S(N,T,V,X)},
$$
which can be rewritten as
$$p^*(N,S,V,X):=p(N,T(N,S,V,X),V,X)=-\frac{\partial U(N,S,V,X) }{\partial V},$$
where often the asterix is dropped.

Now, however, I'm reading that the electron degeneracy pressure of a Fermi gas at low temperatures is defined to be
$$\tilde{p}(N,T=0,V)=-\frac{\partial \tilde{U}(N,T=0,V) }{\partial V}$$
where $\tilde{U}$ is the inner energy in terms of the particle number, temperature and volume. I'm confused, as this definition doesn't match the usual definition of pressure. Is this a different kind of pressure? Why aren't we keeping the entropy constant?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question properly, but don't we have $F=\bar{U}$ at $T=0$? Isn't this a natural consequence of that?

Comment: @NandagopalManoj This makes sense to me, didn't see this at all! I think you should make this an answer, so that I can accept it. Never really thought about it this way..  but yes at absolute zero inner energy and free energy are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we define the free energy as $F = U - TS$, at zero temperature we have $F = U$.

The definition for pressure is
$$
P = -\bigg{(}\frac{\partial F}{\partial V}\bigg{)}_{T,N}
$$
So at $T=0$ we clearly have
$$
P = -\bigg{(}\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\bigg{)}_{T,N}
$$
which is what you call $-\frac{\partial \bar{U}(N,T=0,V)}{\partial V}$. So this matches our natural definition of pressure.